# How to setup an SMTP server on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, email, mamp, osx-mountain-lion

I work with PHP and I have [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) on my machine. I would like to send emails within my PHP code:

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

**How can I configure a mail server for free on my mac machine ?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following did the job. See source [here](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/how-to-enable-local-smtp-server-postfix-on-os-x-leopard/).

1. Edit file: `sudo emacs /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist`.
2. Add `<key>RunAtLoad</key> <true/> <key>KeepAlive</key> <true/>` before the closing `</dict>` tag.
3. Run `sudo postfix start`.

Check that SMPT is running: `telnet localhost 25`

Comment: Even though I'm across after a long time, please update the source. It seems to not work.

Comment: Syed, I didn't write the missing article. Feel free finding a replacement source.

Comment: I didn't have that file, although I did have /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.postfix.master.plist
It didn't have edit permission so I tried just starting the service, which seemed to work by itself.

Answer (score 14):

**Option 1:**

CommandLineFu had this one liner to run an SMTP server on port 25:

```
sudo python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25
```

This will run a fake smtp server on your local machine. It won't send anything, but will dump it to the console.

**Option 2:**

Incase, you are not comfortable with command line then FakeSMTP is a Free Fake SMTP Server with GUI for testing emails in applications easily. It is written in Java. It is very nice and easy to use.

[http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/][1]

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

and if you want an SMTP server to send mail from on OSX, this may help (havent actually tried it, but seems like it could do the job) - http://email.about.com/cs/sendmail/gr/sendmail_enable.htm

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

### [Are there any smtp server i can install on linux mac ?](https://superuser.com/questions/522679/are-there-any-smtp-server-i-can-install-on-linux-mac)

[Sending Mail from PHP Using SMTP Authentication - Example:](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm)

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
 $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "mail.example.com";
 $username = "smtp_username";
 $password = "smtp_password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

[Sending Mail from PHP Using SMTP Authentication and SSL Encryption - Example:](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm)

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
 $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "ssl://mail.example.com";
 $port = "465";
 $username = "smtp_username";
 $password = "smtp_password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

## **Related topics:**

- [Installing a web server on mac](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_make_your_mac_web_server)
- [Mountain lion installing (buying) a web server](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Web-Hosting-With-Mountain-Lion.htm)
- [Leopard install an SMTP server](http://johnbain.org/blog/2008/07/08/configuring-a-smtp-mail-server-on-mac-os-x-leopard/)